# Unable to find numpy/arrayobject.h

Tags: c++, python, numpy

I am trying to build (right now make and install) a library and have been caught at the following error:

`spinal.cpp:3559:10: fatal error: 'numpy/arrayobject.h' file not found 
'#include numpy/arrayobject.h>`

Searching online has shown this to be a common problem that is just fixed by either including it with CPPFLAGS, or export CFLAGS. I tried both and neither worked. I also noted that the location of my header files is significantly different from others.

Mine is: `- I/$HOME/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include`

While most that I see elsewhere is: -I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/

Any suggestions?

Edits (sorry for vagueness):

It's a library called libwireless.

The output of `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.prefix)'` is `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7`.

I tried placing the following into CPPFLAGS as well as trying it with export CFLAGS. 
`-I/$HOME/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include`

Solution found after long time (forgot to note): Things were moved around somehow, so that was actually the incorrect path.

Comment: * Which library are you trying to build? 

* What values did you set for CPPFLAGS and CFLAGS?

* What is the output of - python -c 'import sys; print(sys.prefix)'?